# JSON data keep on returning nil

Tags: json, swift

So I have successfully declared some variables obtained by JsonDictionary, but keep on getting nil, here's my code when declaring the variables:

```
var userName : String!
var text : String!
var name : String!
var tweetID : [NSObject : String]!
var tweetIDStr : String!
var userLocation : String!
var UserImgURLStr : String?
var options : NSJSONReadingOptions!

init(jsonDataDictiony : [String : AnyObject])
{

    self.text = jsonDataDictiony["text"] as! String
    self.tweetIDStr = jsonDataDictiony["id_str"] as! String
    //print(jsonDataDictiony)

    if let userDictionary = jsonDataDictiony["user"] as? [String : AnyObject]
    {

        self.userName = userDictionary["screen_name"] as! String
        self.userLocation = userDictionary["location"] as! String
        self.name = userDictionary["name"] as! String

    }

    print(self.text)
    print(self.userName)
    print(self.userLocation)
    print(self.tweetIDStr)
    print("-")

}

func castStringToDictionary()
{

    let jsonData : NSData = tweetIDStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    self.tweetID = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: options) as! [NSObject : String]
}
```

and this is the code when trying to call the function (different class):

```
var selectedTweet : Tweet!
var twitterNetworkController : NetworkController!
var theTweet = [Tweet]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = selectedTweet.name + "'s tweet"

    twitterNetworkController.fetchTweetID(selectedTweet.tweetID!)
                               //it gets a nil value here ^
    {

        (results, error) in
        if error == nil
        {

            self.theTweet = results!
            self.selectedFeedTableView.reloadData()
        }

        else
        {

           print(error)
        }

    }

}
```

Here's the console print:

["in_reply_to_user_id": , "possibly_sensitive_appealable": 0, "favorite_count": 0, "possibly_sensitive": 0, "in_reply_to_status_id": , "in_reply_to_user_id_str": , "lang": en, "favorited": 0, "id": 736420019152637952, "text":  (at Sate Tegal Marem) — url, "coordinates": , "geo": , "user": {
    "contributors_enabled" = 0;
    "created_at" = "Mon May 21 09:06:46 +0000 2012";
    "default_profile" = 0;
    "default_profile_image" = 0;
    description = "\Uad1c\Ucc2e\Uc744\Ud150\Ub370 \U2b50";
    entities =     {
        description =         {
            urls =             (
            );
        };
    };
    "favourites_count" = 11;
    "follow_request_sent" = 0;
    "followers_count" = 155;
    following = 1;
    "friends_count" = 134;
    "geo_enabled" = 0;
    "has_extended_profile" = 0;
    id = 586390966;
    "id_str" = 586390966;
    "is_translation_enabled" = 0;
    "is_translator" = 0;
    lang = en;
    "listed_count" = 0;
    location = "";
    name = "tania.";
    notifications = 0;
    "profile_background_color" = B4DEBA;
    "profile_background_image_url" = img url;
    "profile_background_image_url_https" = img url;
    "profile_background_tile" = 0;
    "profile_banner_url" = banner url = img url;
    "profile_image_url_https" = img url;
    "profile_link_color" = 44A681;
    "profile_sidebar_border_color" = FFFFFF;
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color" = FFFFFF;
    "profile_text_color" = 333333;
    "profile_use_background_image" = 1;
    protected = 0;
    "screen_name" = "tania_alice";
    "statuses_count" = 2332;
    "time_zone" = Jakarta;
    url = "";
    "utc_offset" = 25200;
    verified = 0;
}, "id_str": 736420019152637952, "created_at": Sat May 28 04:53:09 +0000 2016,

I replaced all the urls since it gave error (my reputation is less than 10 and I cannot post urls)

Comment: Can you share the result of console print out from print(jsonDataDictiony) ?

Comment: There I only posted from 1 tweet, but technically its weird if it returns a nil value @AntonDoudarev

Comment: try putting a break point, and doing a `po jsonDataDictiony["user"]` in the console, if it goes into the if statement, you can do the same thing with `po userDictionary["screen_name"]` could lead you in the right direction